# How to get the text from the textfield in Qt creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qml

I have a QML `TextField` in Qt creator. I want to get the text from the textfield UI.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have 'named' your `TextField`s with `id`s. If an object has an `id`, you can use it as a handle to access properties from it. **For example, imagine you want to clone the text from one textfield to another:**

```
TextField {
  id: textField1
  text: "Text"
}

TextField {
  id: textField2
  text: textField1.text
}
```

You can find more detail [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativeintroduction.html#object-identifiers).

Comment: My problem is i have one textfield and one button. when i click on that button i need to get the text in the textfield and send it to the php server. i have done this project using forms. Now facing problem using the QML.

Comment: Could you add an edit to your question describing the exact context of where you're trying to get the text from and post it to please? Some code snippets would be especially useful in determining what you need :)

Comment: Link is broken.